# Try to find a image exist and send another one instead of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm try to get a image with 2 selectbox matches it works but i try if there isn't a img shows sa.jpg instead of matches.

```
$(document).on('click', '#buton', function() {

      $se1 = $('#se1 option:selected').text();
      $se2 = $('#se2 option:selected').text();
      var image = "'./img/' + $se1 + $se2 + '.jpg'";

      if ($(this).attr('src', './img/' + $se1 + $se2 + '.jpg').length > 0 ){
         $('#imge').attr('src', './img/sa.jpg');  
      } else {
         $('#imge').attr('src', './img/' + $se1 + $se2 + '.jpg');
      }

});
```

Comment: You are setting attribute `asd`(???) in checking condition. Your code nor your question doesn't make sense to me. You should better describe what you are expecting here

Comment: are you trying to check if image exists on server? and if not then show a temporary image ?

Comment: yes @S4beR
Sorry trying different things i forget to change that. ı'm trying this;
1-dropdown 2- dropdown
   Horse            jungle         if this match has a image it shows up 

but if there isn't a image than sa.jpg shows up .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `onerror` event of `img` as below

```
$('#image').attr('src', './img/' + $se1 + $se2 + '.jpg');

$('#image').on("error", function() {
    $('#image').attr('src', './img/sa.jpg');
});
```

check this plnkr example for more reference
https://plnkr.co/edit/5BszVgD9d1qtMHFO0Ymb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the image exist using `$.get` in JQuery ([**documentation here**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)):

```
$(document).on('click', '#buton', function() {
  var imageUrl;
  var imageElement = $('#imge');

  $se1 = $('#se1 option:selected').text();
  $se2 = $('#se2 option:selected').text();
  imageUrl = './img/' + $se1 + $se2 + '.jpg';

  $.get(imageUrl)
    .done(function() {
      imageElement.attr('src', imageUrl);

    }).fail(function() {
      imageElement.attr('src', './img/sa.jpg');
    });
});
```